# How to compare one column value available or not in another column dataframe and extract another column of second dataframe if present

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes like below -

```
df1_data = {'id' :{0:'101',1:'102',2:'103',3:'104',4:'105'},
        'sym1' :{0:'abc',1:'pqr',2:'xyz',3:'mno',4:'lmn'},
        'a name' :{0:'a',1:'b',2:'c',3:'d',4:'e'}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data)
print df1

df2_data = {'sym2' :{0:'abc',1:'xxx',2:'xyz'},
            'a name' :{0:'k',1:'e',2:'t'}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data)
print df2
```

I want to check sym1 available in df1 present in sym2 column of df2 or not and if present I want to extract that row's **a name** and add it into df1 as a new column **new_col**.

For that purpose I tried below snippet and it is working too but for my long dataframes it is not working. I'm facing below error and warning message -

```
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
```

**code snippet -**

```
df1['root'] = df2[df1['sym1'].isin(df2.sym2)]['a name']
print df1
```

How I can grab these a name column from df2 and make new_col in df1 for particular row?

Comment: Do you need anymore information here as to why you got the IndexingError or is the working example below sufficient enough?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a typical merge operation. In your particular case, you have two different data frames sharing an identifier column (sym1 and sym2) which align corresponding rows (or identities) that *belong together*. All you need to do is a merge on those identifier columns:

```
>>> to_merge = df2.rename(columns={"a name": "new_col"}) # rename to desired column name
>>> df_merged = pd.merge(df1, to_merge, how="left", left_on="sym1", right_on="sym2")

>>> print(df_merged)

    a name      id     sym1      new_col    sym2
0      a        101     abc        k        abc
1      b        102     pqr        NaN      NaN
2      c        103     xyz        t        xyz
3      d        104     mno        NaN      NaN
4      e        105     lmn        NaN      NaN
```

See the pandas merge documentation for more information [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).